# Unable to draw logo with correct strokes and shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, stroke, symbols

I am trying to design a logo for my company. However I have tried for 12 hours now making the design below, but I have huge problems getting what I want.

I want the road to be crossing the other one like it was a bridge. It should not look like a intersection like it does now. Can someone give me instructions to how to manage to create a shape like this?

[image]

This is what I have.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do all this with a single stroke?? Things really depend upon *how* you currently have objects constructed.

In order to get the appearance of an "overlap" you need an overlap. So draw a section of road to cover the overall path:

[image]

Same stroke style applied to an additional path on top of the base path. You won't be able to create the appearance of an overlap, regarding the white stroke, with a single path and the Appearance Panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To deal with those hairline bits that appear on the ends due to anti-aliasing, you can add an **Effect** the the base black stroke. This is really just a drawing anti-aliasing artifact and won't be visible on export (Art Optimized) or in print. But if it bothers you or you are uncertain it really isn't an issue, you can tweak things to remove it.

[image]

Highlight the base stroke... Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` from the menu. Enter a very small scale change in the top two fields of the Transform Options dialog window:

[image]

This will cause the black base stroke to be slightly larger than the underlying white stroke, and subsequently remove that hairline you may see.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61947/discussion-on-answer-by-metis-unable-to-draw-logo-with-correct-strokes-and-shado).

Comment: Any time I have an idea I have to remind myself: there's a very good chance that someone somewhere has already thought of that before me; that what I want to do has already been done before... It's always a good idea just to check and see: [infinity symbol road](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=702&q=infinity+symbol+road&oq=infinity+symbol+road&gs_l=img.3...2006.2006.0.3097.1.1.0.0.0.0.268.268.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.img..0.0.0.35iM6bPv-Fk)

Comment: @BANG And how does that help me? It was not the design that I had problem with. It was how I should do it in Illustrator.

Comment: @Metis May I ask how you created your infinity symbol?

Comment: @Andreas My point is this: Are you sure someone doesn't already use a logo just like the one you're making?

Comment: @BANG Yes, it is only a small part of it.

Comment: @Andreas The first one in the first screen shot above I just drew with the pen tool... the second one in the animation.. I took more care and created 2 circles, deleted middle anchors then drew connection paths between the 2 circles.

Comment: @Metis I am a beginnner in AI, could you record/take an image of it and edit your answer with your approach? To see if that is better than what I do?

Comment: There's really no "wrong" way to construct the symbol as long as it appears as you like it. In short.. 2 circles, delete anchors, join opposite anchors, Convert Path Tool to create smooth points.. add guide to center, extend anchor handles to center guide. [Animated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsXm.gif) Also note I *prefer* working in CS6... so there may be additional methods in CC (Via the curvature tool or other newer features)

Comment: The reason I asked is because the way I was doing it I could not get the dotted lines to align when you paste the section that overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little bit easier way to make this:

- Draw a perfect circle and add a nice thick stroke to it. This will be the base of the road
- Duplicate the circle, move it over. Group them and center them on the artboard, then ungroup them again

Result:

[image: Two circles]

- Hit the <kbd>A</kbd> key to grab the Direct Selection Tool
- Drag a selection over the center of both circles and press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key:

[image: Two semicircles]

- Hit the <kbd>P</kbd> key to grab the Pen Tool and make a path to connect the top of one semicircle to the bottom of the other:

[image: The centerpiece]

- Hit the <kbd>A</kbd> key again, click on the part you just drew and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to copy that section of the path and paste it in front:

[image: Copy and paste in front]

- With that piece selected, hit the <kbd>O</kbd> key to grab the Reflect tool, and while holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, click in the center to bring up the Reflect dialog, choose  Horizontal (or Vertical in this case) and press 'OK':

[image: Reflect dialog]

So this is what we want to see at this point (colors changed for demonstration only):

[image: Two paths]

- Before adding strokes to round out the appearance, select both paths and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to make a compound path
- Go into the Appearance Panel flyout menu (blue arrow below) and deselect 'New Art Has Basic Appearance':

[image: Appearance Panel flyout menu]

Now add your new strokes as desired to make your road. When you get to the dashed yellow stroke change it to 'Projecting Cap' and also set it so Illustrator 'Aligns dashes to corners and path ends, adjusting lengths to fit'. This way all of your dashes will line up nicely...

Now we're at this point:

[image: Compound road]

(This is the point you were already at but I had no idea how you got there... My method assumes that it was done my way from the start.

If you've done it the way I've shown here then all you have to do now is release the compound path (Object > Compound Path > Release) and you're done:

[image: Final result]